# Filter source files in solution in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a lot of files and projects in my solution. I am looking for something to filter them similar to the way you filter stored procedures or other items in sql server management studio.

Is there anything similar?

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: in VS20120, hit `Ctrl-;`, start typing and hit Enter

Answer (score 0):

U can take help of this:
This tool is good.

http://slntools.codeplex.com/

or follow these links:

http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/fis.asp

http://www.schwammysays.net/visual-studio-2012-tip-solution-explorer-filters/